# Fill input update form modal with ajax

Tags: javascript

I would like to edit a a table record using a bootstrap modal, I've tryed to load the input form inside the modal using ajax and it works fine except for the date field, if the date is present in the databse there is no problem but if the date in the databse is null then it says "Invalid date" instead would like to show something "insert date of birth"

This is my javascript code:

```
function GetUserDetail(id) {

      $("#user_id").val(id);

      var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

      $.ajax({  

        url:"../controllers/ctrl_admin_user_app/ctrl_admin_get_user_details.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{user_id:user_id},  
        dataType:"json",  

        success: function(data){  

         $('#firstName').val(data.nome);  
         $('#lastName').val(data.cognome);  
         $('#userEmail').val(data.email);  
         $('#userTel').val(data.telefono);  
         $('#userFiscalcode').val(data.codice_fiscale);  
         $('#userDocument').val(data.documento);
         $('#userBirth').val(moment(data.data_nascita).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
         $("#EditUserModal").modal("show");

       } 

     }); 

    }
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Check to see what data.data_nascita is equal to and if it is null or whatever it is returning that causes your date formatting to fail, then if it is a valid date format it else show your insert date of birth

Comment: So check that the date !== null before setting the value to your input : `if (data.data_nascita) $('#userBirth').val(moment(data.data_nascita).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));`

Comment: Hi @Striped this works fine the only problem I've got now is if I open the modal for a user who has the date of birth set up and then I open the modal for one without date of birth set up it keep the value form the previous modal, is there nay way to fix it? many thanks

Comment: Initialise your modal default values to empty strings for text, and find the default value for date, I don't really know what the date type input has as default value.

Comment: Ok i've found this:   $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
      }); is it the right way? I put it just after: function GetUserDetail(id) {
and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the data is `null` or `undefined` before (or while) setting the `.val();`

```
$('#userBirth').val((typeof data.data_nascita != 'undefined') ? moment(data.data_nascita).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : 'Insert Date of Birth');
```

This basically is:

```
if(typeof data.data_nascita != 'undefined') {
    $('#userBirth').val(moment(data.data_nascita).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
} else { // It's undefined
    $('#userBirth').val('Please Enter Date of Birth');
}
```